# MS Detours - DetourAttach on GetTickCount fails with ERROR_INVALID_BLOCK

Tags: winapi, hook, detours

I've been bumping my head against this for a while now. I've been using Microsoft Detours successfully except for this one case.

I'm trying to hook `WINBASEAPI DWORD WINAPI GetTickCount(VOID);` from Kernel32.dll. DetourAttach always returns ERROR_INVALID_BLOCK.

From the docs:

```
ERROR_INVALID_BLOCK 
  The function referenced is too small to be detoured.
```

I've seen numerous other people hook this function successfully with Detours but I just can't get it. I don't care about calling the original function after detouring.

I'm using Detours Express 3.0 with 32bit applications on Windows 7 x64.

Anyone have any ideas?

Complete code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "include\detours.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "detours.lib" )

BOOL(WINAPI *Orig_QueryPerformanceCounter)(LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount) = QueryPerformanceCounter;
BOOL WINAPI New_QueryPerformanceCounter(LARGE_INTEGER *lpPerformanceCount) {
    printf("QueryPerformanceCounter()\n");
    return 0;
}

DWORD(WINAPI * Orig_GetTickCount)() = GetTickCount;
DWORD WINAPI New_GetTickCount() {
    printf("GetTickCount()\n");
    return 0;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID) {
    switch (dwReason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        LONG error = DetourTransactionBegin();
        if (error != NO_ERROR) {
            printf("DetourTransactionBegin failed with error: %d.\n", error);
            return FALSE;
        }

        error = DetourUpdateThread(::GetCurrentThread());
        if (error != NO_ERROR) {
            printf("DetourUpdateThread failed with error: %d.\n", error);
            return FALSE;
        }

        //DetourSetIgnoreTooSmall(TRUE); // Doesn't help

        // Works fine
        error = DetourAttach(&(PVOID &)Orig_QueryPerformanceCounter, New_QueryPerformanceCounter);
        if (error != NO_ERROR) {
            printf("DetourAttach QueryPerformanceCounter failed with error: %d.\n", error);
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Fails here, with error = 9
        error = DetourAttach(&(PVOID &)Orig_GetTickCount, New_GetTickCount);
        if (error != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("DetourAttach GetTickCount failed with error: %d.\n", error); 
        return FALSE;
        }

        error = DetourTransactionCommit();
        if (error != NO_ERROR) {
            printf("DetourTransactionCommit failed with error: %d.\n", error);
            return FALSE;
        }

        break;
    }
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    {
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID &)Orig_QueryPerformanceCounter, New_QueryPerformanceCounter);
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID &)Orig_GetTickCount, New_GetTickCount);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: When you say `I've seen numerous other people hook this function successfully with Detours`, do you have any examples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823887/hooking-gettickcount-with-c?rq=1 suggests `GetTickCount` doesn't have the necessary "preamble" for Detours to work successfully.

Comment: Odd quirk, GetProcAddress() returns the address of GetTickCountStub instead of GetTickCount.  Well, can't work.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more that this seems to me to be an instance of the XY Problem.  What actual task are you trying to accomplish by hooking `GetTickCount`? It might turn out to be impossible to override the functionality of `GetTickCount`, but there might be better ways to accomplish the final result.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I checked out QPC in IDA and it seems to be basically identical with just a jmp and no preamble, and it works fine. In this case I would atleast expect to be able to hook it but not be able to call the original function anymore? // 

theB: I ended up using mhook and it worked great with it, I really expected Detours to be able to do the job though. I'm still pretty curious why Detours couldn't get it though.

Comment: Tested your code with Detours 2 Professional, VS2008 compiler and Windows 7, works like a charm.